# Change button theme when pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to change the data-theme of a button when pressed.

I'm calling this JavaScript function in the button's onClick handler:

```
function changeNextButtonColor() {
    var nextButton = document.getElementById('next');
    nextButton.setAttribute('data-theme', 'a');
}
```

but the theme is not changing. Any ideas?

Comment: Your code works; something else is going wrong. What does the JavaScript console (Web Inspector, Firebug, Dragonfly...) say? Are any errors reported?

Comment: Thanks guys! Maybe is not working because the button is an input submit? <input type="submit" name="next" id="next" value="NEXT" class="navButton" onclick="changeNextButtonColor();" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-theme="c" data-iconpos="right">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've set set the theme on the button you'll need to call "refresh" on it like this below...

```
$("#next").attr("data-theme","a").button('refresh');
```

If you want to bind this kind of behavior to all "next" buttons in a process and their might be more than one then you might want to consider doing something more like this.   It will checked every page for a button that has a class of colorChangeButton and then, when clicked, change the theme to the alternate theme specified on that buttons attribute of data-theme-pressed.

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" class="colorChangeButton" data-theme-pressed="a" data-theme="b">Next</a>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('div').live('pageinit', function(){
        $("a.colorChangeButton).click(function(){
           var $thisButton = $(this);
           $thisButton.attr("data-theme",$thisButton.attr("data-theme-pressed")).button('refresh');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function changeNextButtonColor() {
    $('#next').attr({'data-theme': 'a'});
}
```

If you're using jQuery, this is your code.