# Issue with dynamically changing data-theme in split button listview

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

I am trying to follow the outline [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8554853/194742) to dynamically change the color swatch of a split button list view by changing the data-theme. Interestingly, the scheme works when I put in an alert statement in the javascript, but when I take the alert out, this doesn't work well.

Here is the sample:

- With alert: http://jsbin.com/ifodij/4/
- Without alert: http://jsbin.com/ifodij/3/ (try toggling on two buttons before trying to toggle off)

Any suggestion as to why this is happening and what I might be missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure as to the cause. But this is how I would re-write what you are doing (which appears to fix the problem):

Firstly, remove your inline javascript (`onclick="toggleChecked('2', 'TR02')"`) from the HTML.

Next, replace your `toggleChecked()` function with the following javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a[id^="star"]').on("click", function(){

      if ($(this).data("theme") == "d") {
         $(this).buttonMarkup({ theme: 'e' }).button();
      } else {
         $(this).buttonMarkup({ theme: 'd' }).button();
      }
   });
});
```

The above is an event listener, that will check to see when any anchor with an `id` starting with `star` is clicked.

Refreshing the button appears to be a bit buggy, often classes from the previous theme hang around despite rebuilding the button.

---

**UPDATE**

Actually scrap the above, it seems like such a convoluted way of achieving a selected button. Why not just change the CSS, using the above as a guide, remove the inline styles and use the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a[id^="star"]').on("click",function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("ui-btn-pressed");
   }); 
});
```

Here is a jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ifodij/8/edit

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I also need the number after star in the ID, either by directly passing to a function (which is what I was trying to do), or by some other means. I need to update the theme and do some other stuff. Any ideas?

Comment: Moving "$(this).toggleClass('ui-btn-pressed');" into the toggleChecked() function seems to solve it nicely. Thanks again.

Comment: No problems. Using my code, you could get the id's number by doing something like `var id_number = $(this).attr('id').replace('star',''); ` . Just pop it after the toggleClass line. http://jsbin.com/ifodij/9/edit

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately the above accepted answer didnot work for me to change the split icon theme,
  I solved my problem form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485493/jquery-mobile-change-switch-theme-on-listview-data-split-icon)     `$(this).find('span.ui-btn').buttonMarkup({
   theme: 'b'
});`