# jQuery Mobile: change/switch theme on listview data-split-icon

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, icons, data-theme

I have split listview (with collapsible set) in jQuery Mobile (jQm). You can see it [here on JSfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/BxFsC/8/)

I want the split icon act as checkbox. The icon has default `data-theme="c"` so it is grey and I want to change the `data-theme` to `b` on click, so the icon color should change to blue.

I tried different solutions to change `data-theme` and found several more or less (more the less) working solution. The best is simple jQm code  `$(this).buttonMarkup({theme: 'b'});`, but, changing data theme this way dont change color of icon, but only change color of its background, as you can try in [mentioned JSfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/BxFsC/8/)

Normaly `data-theme` on split listview, will only affect icon, but when it is changed this way, it affects icons background. I want to change only icon, not its background and I cannot find way to do that. Probably wrong selector or some kind of bug.

What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the below to your code.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/BxFsC/11/)**

```js
$(this).find('span.ui-btn').buttonMarkup({
   theme: 'b'
});
```

and

```js
$(this).find('span.ui-btn').buttonMarkup({
   theme: 'c'
});
```

As `span.ui-btn` holds the icon and its' style.